# Why was the protocol removed from my URLs?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, specific-edit

A high-rep user removed the `https` part from URLs in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208703/how-to-raise-a-number-to-a-power/51208704#51208704) of mine.

For example, from

```
https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/fn.pow.html
```

to

```
://docs.rs/num/latest/num/fn.pow.html
```

I'd like to understand the rationale behind this change.

The URL seems different from a [protocol-relative URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Protocol-relative_URLs) in that it starts with a colon¹.

The edit in question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51208704/6).

---

¹ I misinterpreted the colon and thought it belonged to the URL. In truth, the colon belongs to the Markup syntax. The whole line is `[1]://docs.rs/num/latest/num/fn.pow.html`. Thus, the URL is indeed protocol-relative.

Thanks for clearing that up and apologies for causing a stir.

Comment: I can't think of a valid reason for such a change, but I suspect that it was a byproduct of the markjdown editor because the answer is actually rendered with protocol-relative URLs, not the weird empty-protocol URLs that now appear in the markdown.  The main thing the edit seems to do with those is convert from the markdown from inline URL style to footnote URL style.  Personally I would have rejected the edit for "no improvement" if I had come across it in the review queue, but the user who edited has enough rep to bypass review.

Comment: Note that the colon isn't actually part of the relative URLs, it's part of the link Markdown.

Comment: @leonheess your edit, which just removes the colon, fundamentally changes the core of the question, because the OP also indicates that it is not a protocol-relative URL, which your changes converts it to. And if you remove that mention as well, the confusion of the OP probably disappears and it just boils down to “is this a valid edit?”.

Comment: It's not immediately clear from the question if the confusion at least *partially* stems from the misinterpretation of the colon, which is why I mentioned this in a *comment*, rather than straight up editing the question. If anyone should edit the question, it's the OP, not someone else on their behalf.

Comment: **Moderator note:** Please don't edit the question again. See Didier L's comment. Matthias has clarified this in a flag and I've answered the question as-is.

Comment: @DidierL that was confusion by the OP. The colon isn't part of the link. Also, it isn't even relevant to the question. Anyone that has worked with browsers know what removing the protocol is.

Comment: @Braiam that confusion is an important part of the question, which should thus be addressed in answers. It is thus very relevant to the question, unless the author themself specifies otherwise (which is the case now but was not then). See also the moderator note and the accepted answer.

Comment: @DidierL that confusion is irrelevant. OP lack of knowledge about markdown shouldn't prevent us from correcting that misunderstanding and informing that it has nothing to do with the inquiry put in front of us: why was the protocol removed. All other things just distract from it.

Comment: @Braiam: That confusion is the **entire point** of this question, whether you like it or not. It's answered, move on.

Comment: @BoltClock no, the confusion is removing the protocol, not the colon. Move on.

Comment: @Braiam In case you missed it, there's a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407239/why-was-the-protocol-removed-from-my-urls#comment840663_407239) from a moderator instructing users *not* to edit this post. I don't know if your edit conflicts with the intent of that comment, but you might want to get some clarification before making the edit.

Comment: @cigien: The edit doesn't directly conflict the way leonheess's edits did, but it does, ironically, exacerbate the confusion considering the full line was already mentioned in a footnote, so both samples are now just the same. So many people change one or two specific parts of a post without doing the work to maintain consistency across the entire thing. Based on their last reply to Didier L who acknowledged my mod note, the fact that I was the one who left the note, and their reply to me imitating my language (a common rhetorical device I don't know the name of), I don't think they missed it.

Comment: @cigien: Anyway, all that matters is that this edit reintroduces confusion to the question. I don't want Matthias to continue receiving notifications for this as they have presumably moved on, so I'll be locking it for good so that I can finally do the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the editor in a deleted answer (for the benefit of sub-10k users):

- The change to protocol-relative URLs was to remove unnecessary characters from URLs that were going to resolve to HTTPS anyway.
- The change to reference notation for Markdown links was stylistic.

As I mentioned in my comment, the colons are part of this reference notation, not the URLs. Therefore, what you're looking at *are* indeed the protocol-relative URLs you're familiar with. With that out of the way, let's talk about the edit itself.

Protocol-relative URLs are considered unnecessary in the age of HTTPS-by-default — while things like HTTP Strict Transport Security, server-side HTTP-to-HTTPS redirects, and Stack Exchange itself being HTTPS are nice to have, having links that point to HTTPS URLs doesn't hurt, and changing them to protocol-relative has no positive impact on end users. If an edit does nothing to improve a post's links (examples of improvements include repairing broken links, changing them to point to a canonical mirror of the *same* content, etc), the edit shouldn't be made at all, as it would unnecessarily bump the post (particularly if it's been inactive for quite some time).

Similarly, we discourage edits that simply change the Markdown style and don't materially improve the post (unless perhaps the edits are removing things like extreme amounts of excess line breaks or whitespace that somehow made their way into the post content). I guess you could make a case for making it easier for other editors, but even putting aside the *author's* editing style, everyone has their own style, and what works better for you may not necessarily be effective for other editors — it may even be the complete opposite. You're just moving other people's cheese for the sake of it, while doing absolutely nothing for the usefulness or readability of the post itself.

Edits that modify or add content to a post using the editor's own style are less of an issue here and can be discussed separately.

Comment: "*changing them to protocol-relative has a net impact of zero on end users*" disagreed. If I copy the post (or part of the post), I lose the HTTPS context. I'm still an end user of the post even if I don't see it on Stack Overflow. But my experience has now been changed. If I move that part of the post to a comment in the code, and it mentions a protocol-relative URL like `//example.com` that now means something completely different to `https://example.com` or `http://example.com` - restoring that context is more burdensome than just not removing it at all.

Comment: @VLAZ: I don't follow. Do you mean copying the link from the post's Markdown? Is there a reason you wouldn't use Copy Link from the rendered post instead which would ensure you obtain an absolutized URL ([other than the extremely frustrating change that was recently made to Firefox](https://twitter.com/NOVALISTIC/status/1385257291629219844))?

Comment: @VLAZ: If you're referring to something like copying it to a different CMS that uses Markdown, then that's a fair argument, because I do that too sometimes (my site, for example, uses Markdown for *everything*). All the more we should explicitly specify HTTPS then...

Comment: It could be an archived copy of the post. It could also be a comment for code - either in actual code or perhaps in the code review tool of choice. It's often easier to copy the markdown for many places already support them. Or perhaps copy it as it can easily be converted to normal text: `See [FooWubberFactoryManager](http://example.com/some/documentation)` -> `See  FooWubberFactoryManager (http://example.com/some/documentation)`

Comment: @VLAZ: I changed it to "no positive impact".